# Variables in Photoionization and Work Function of metals

Tags: photons, material-science, metals, nanoscience

Do metals engaged in coordination bond have the same work function and/or photoionization of the pure metal? The outer electron shell still remains the same.
If photoionization were to happen, what would be the underlying result? There is a very complicated relationship in the electron behaviour of this environment.